# Download shapefiles from website with embedded Google map

Tags: shapefile, google-maps

I would like to download all the blue highlighted regions on this map so that I can import them into other mapping software. The map with all the data is at the bottom of the page with the title "Find Nearby Zones". Here is a link to the website: https://www.backcountryrecon.com/colorado/the-gore-range/big-bad-wolf/

Here is a screenshot showing an example of the blue regions I want to download:
[image]

Here is another screenshot showing all the areas (far too many for me to draw by hand):
[image]

I tried using developer tools to capture a .json file but did not have any luck. I also tried to inspect the page and tried to see if the map had any built-in download tools. Honestly, I don't know where to start on downloading this data. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @user2856 That worked! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Be aware that some sites may have terms and conditions that prevent you from legally scraping their data.  When in doubt, ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't download shapefiles from that site.

You can grab the KML files and convert to any format you like though. Use developer tools, search for "kml_layers_links" in the index.

```
{"kml_layers_links":["http:\/\/www.backcountryrecon.com\/maps\/gore-range\/Big-Bad-Wolf.kml?x=1636936663"]}
```

and

```
{"kml_layers_links":["http:\/\/www.backcountryrecon.com\/maps\/Index.kml?v=20&x=1636936663"]}
```

So download http://www.backcountryrecon.com/maps/gore-range/Big-Bad-Wolf.kml and http://www.backcountryrecon.com/maps/Index.kml